# Remove/add a class and then execute an event on this new class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to change a class:

```
$('.fa.fa-plus-circle').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-minus-circle");
    });
});
```

Then I used

```
$('.fa.fa-minus-circle').each(function () {
     $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-plus-circle");
     });
});
```

So for the first one "fa.fa-plus-circle" that is the default when the page is loading, everything is good and the class changes. But when the class changes I can't do anything else after, JQuery continues to execute

```
$('.fa.fa-plus-circle').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-minus-circle");
    });
});
```

Why ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegate for this, because you are adding the classes dynamically.

```
$(document).on("click", '.fa.fa-minus-circle', function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-plus-circle");
});

$(document).on("click", '.fa.fa-plus-circle', function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-minus-circle");
});
```

Also there is no need for looping through the elements for binding the event.

**But the recommended approach will be**,

```
$('.fa').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle");
});
```

**Edit**

```
$(document).on("click", ".fa", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle");
});
```

Comment: no looping ?? event when I got a table with the same class on many elements ? That's works well by the way.. !! But I don't understand why it works without loop ? :|

Comment: did you try the last approach?

Comment: yes the class works well with the toogleClass the only thing is I need to run some ajax code in function of the class.. so the 1st approach is more appropriated no ?

Comment: Yes the edited code works perfect.. thanks a lot !! and thanks also for the toggleClass because for sure I will re-use it later =)

Comment: nice tip about using multiple classnames in toggle.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `.fa-minus-circle` when it loads, so the each loop never happens. Even if you removed the each loop (which isn't required) it wouldn't add the listeners because it wouldn't find the selector. So, you have to use the delegates version of `on` which looks something like this...

```
$('body').on('click','.fa-minus-circle',function () {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("fa fa-minus-circle");
});
```

fwiw, you could just use one class and `toggleClass` Then put all your `fa-plus-circle` code into the `fa` class since that is the default behavior.

```
$('body').on('click','.fa',function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus-circle");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a benefit to not removing all classes. There seems no point to removing `.fa` so that you can add it. Which means that your code should be:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", '.fa.fa-minus-circle', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-minus-circle').addClass("fa-plus-circle");
    });

    $(document).on("click", '.fa.fa-plus-circle', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-plus-circle').addClass("fa-minus-circle");
    });
});
```

And as @AnoopJoshi has pointed out, you can use the `.toggleClass()` method:

```
$(function() {
    $('.fa').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
    });
});
```

Comment: fwiw "If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed." --http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: Good point; must have glossed over the square brackets indicating optional. Thanks!